# Anyone knows how many mAh in iPod Touch 4th generation battery?

Tags: ipod-touch, battery

Does anyone know how many mAh does the iPod Touch 4th generation battery have? Seems like Apple doesn't provide this particular info.

Comment: You could search for an image of the factory battery in a photo that someone takes of an iPod Touch that they opened up. Ideally the battery would have its capacity labeled, unless it's an Apple part or Apple had the product details obscured (which happens a lot with Apple devices, I hear). I'm searching for such an image now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

930 mAh (3.44 watt hours). Up from the previous generation's 789 mAh (2.92 watt hours) battery.

Sources: [[1]](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPod-Touch-4th-Generation-Teardown/3562/2) [[2]](http://www.everythingusb.com/apple-ipod-touch-4-20040.html)

Comment: You won this round! :)

Answer (score 3):

**[iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPod-Touch-4th-Generation-Teardown/3562/2)** disassembled the 4th generation iPod touch.

On their photo, you can see that the battery has **3.44Wh**.
This calculates to **930mAh** since the battery runs at **3.7V**.

[image]

[image]